# Scroll only the modal

Tags: css

I made a Modal with a set height and width.

When I click the button to open the Modal, a new class (`.modal-open`) is added to the `BODY` tag. Now the `BODY` is not able to scroll. That's what I wanted, no problems.

```
.modal-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

[image]

What I'm trying to do now is what I can't figure it out.

I wanted to block the body to scroll AND don't set a `height` property for the Modal, so I could scroll the content of the Modal without the `Y` scroll. Like this:

[image]

What I could do to be able to scroll the entire content of the Modal and don't get stuck?

Here it is my CSS Modal class:

```
.my-modal {
  background-color: $color-ink;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  &__content {
    position: fixed;
    // overflow-y: scroll;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50vw;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    border-radius: 5px;
    max-width: 60rem;
    // height: 50vh;
  }
}
```

Comment: SOLVED: I was taking away the overflow from the entire Body of my page with my class so even the content of the modal was not scrollable anymore. So I added a new util class to the background of my modal with ```overflow-y: scroll !important``` and removed the properties ```overflow-y``` and ```height``` of the content, as it is in my question above.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to know for sure without seeing the rest of your code. But assuming the Content element is INSIDE the `my-modal` you should use `position: absolute` instead of fixed for the inner one.

Position fixed produces strange effects as its tied to the body in ways that position absolute isn't. Absolute references the next explicitly positioned parent element in the stack so your placement should remain unchanged.

After you do that, `height` and `overflow-y` on the content should produce the effect you're expecting.

Comment: Hi, Bryce. After I posted here, I changed to 'absolute' just to try things. It worked the same but better, like you said. But the freezing effect keeps in. Thank you for your anwser!

Comment: When you say "freezing", does that mean that the scroll works but seems to lag or stick sometimes? That sounds like a different issue most likely a browser memory thing. Do you have a bunch of tabs open or a lot of CSS transforms happening?

Comment: Sorry for the description. I mean, in the <body> I add the .modal-open class (overflow: hidden), then nothing scrolls. So I tryed to don't add the overflow: hidden to the body tag. Now I can see the scroll in the entire page but the content of the Modal keeps fixed (even when absolute is the property I'm using). *Edit: now I think that I know why: my-modal (parent node) got the property 'fixed' himself, so obviously the content of the modal is going to stay absolute to the parent fixed. Maybe if I take the content from the inside of the my-modal node, and work with Z-Indexes... I'll try.